# Is there PostGIS equivalent to arcpy.sa.Slice() function?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

I have an existing system built on an 8.3 PostgreSQL database which uses a ArcGIS - Spatial Analyst for a couple of raster operations.  The system is moving to PostgreSQL 9.2 and I'm evaluating if the Spatial Analyst piece is actually needed.  But I'm not at all familiar with PostGIS's raster capabilities, and couldn't find an equivalent function during my initial search.

The actual function call is:
[`arcpy.sa.Slice(xras, zonecount, "NATURAL_BREAKS")`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000ss000000.htm)

[From the Esri Help Docs:](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000ss000000.htm)

> Slices or reclassifies the range of values of the input cells into
>   zones of equal interval, equal area, or by natural breaks.
>
> - Slice works best on data that is normally distributed. When using    input raster data that is skewed the output result may not contain
>     all of the classes that you had expected or specified.
> - If an environment Mask has been set, those cells that have been masked will    receive NoData on the output slice raster.
> - When using the EQUAL_AREA    method, sometimes not all of the output classes will have an equal,    or even similar, number of cells
>     (i.e., area). This may be an    inherent result based on the nature of
>     the input values and the    specified number of classes (bins). If the
>     results are deemed    undesirable, you can try using a few number of
>     classes or applying a    statistics transformation (e.g., logarithm,
>     square root, and so on)    to the input dataset.

Comment: Not sure about PostGIS command, but I would guess between using either GRASS GIS or GDAL you could do that.

Comment: @artwork21 I was hoping to bring the raster piece into the existing database transaction.

Comment: What does that function do?  If you can tell me that, I can probably tell you if PostGIS raster supports it or can easily by writing some wrapper plpgsql or plpython or some other take your pick PL language.

Comment: ST_Reclass with the reclassarg option seems to be the closest http://postgis.net/docs/reclassarg.html

Comment: The other day I stumbled upon that:  http://qgissextante.blogspot.gr/2013/01/dividing-in-equal-area-zones.html . It should help you formulate the strategy if needed for the equal area case.